# how to restart jenkins service inside pod in kubernetes cluster

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I have created a kubernetes cluster and deployed jenkins by following file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: jenkins-ci
spec:
 replicas: 1
 template:
  metadata:
   labels:
    run: jenkins-ci
  spec:
    containers:
    - name: jenkins-ci
      image: jenkins:2.32.2 
      ports:
      - containerPort: 8080
```

and service by

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: jenkins-cli-lb
spec: 
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    # the port that this service should serve on
    - port: 8080
      nodePort: 30000
  # label keys and values that must match in order to receive traffic for this service
  selector: 
    run: jenkins-ci
```

Now i can access jenkins UI in my browser without any problems. My issue I came into situation in which need to restart jenkins service manually??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `kubectl delete pods -l run=jenkins-ci` - Will delete all pods with this label (your jenkins containers).
Since they are under Deployment, it will re-create the containers. Network routing will be adjusted automatically (again because of the label selector).

See https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/

Answer (score 0):

You can use command below to enter the pod container.

```
$ kubectl exec -it kubernetes pod -- /bin/bash
```

After apply service Jenkins restart command.

For more details please refer :[how to restart service inside pod in kubernetes cluster](https://devopsmanual.in/2018/03/28/how-to-restart-service-inside-pod-in-kubernetes-cluster/).